# How can I pass main's *argv[] to a function?

Tags: c, pointers, command-line-arguments

I have a program that can accept command-line arguments and I want to access the arguments, entered by the user, from a function. How can I pass the `*argv[]`, from `int main( int argc, char *argv[])` to that function ? I'm kind of new to the concept of pointers and `*argv[]` looks a bit too complex for me to work this out on my own.

The idea is to leave my `main` as clean as possible by moving all the work, that I want to do with the arguments, to a library file. I already know what I have to do with those arguments when I manage to get hold of them outside the `main`. I just don't know how to get them there.

I am using GCC.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just write a function such as

```
void parse_cmdline(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // whatever you want
}
```

and call that in `main` as `parse_cmdline(argc, argv)`. No magic involved.

In fact, you don't really need to pass `argc`, since the final member of `argv` is guaranteed to be a null pointer. But since you have `argc`, you might as well pass it.

If the function need not know about the program name, you can also decide to call it as

```
parse_cmdline(argc - 1, argv + 1);
```

Comment: What about when argv is defined as const char *argv[]? That's how OS X is, and I can't exactly change Apple's ABI...

Comment: @MarcusJ Yeah -- ARC does get in the way of that in XCode on OSX. I had to pass them to my ObjC++ class method like `getParams(argc,argv)`, but then had to declare that function like `static std::map<std::string,std::string> getParams(int argc, const char **argv)` Note the `**argv`. Then, inside the class method, I could use `argv` as normal as if it were in the `main` function. (The `map` stuff on the return result was because my function converted the variables into key=value map pairs. Not that you might do that also.)

Answer (score 3):

```
SomeResultType ParseArgs( size_t count, char**  args ) {
    // parse 'em
}
```

Or...

```
SomeResultType ParseArgs( size_t count, char*  args[] ) {
    // parse 'em
}
```

And then...

```
int main( int size_t argc, char* argv[] ) {
    ParseArgs( argv );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass `argc` and `argv` to your function.