# Pass Variable Arguments From One Function To Other Function

Tags: c

I have a function in foo.c which recevies variable arguments from Console

**foo.c**

```
void Function1 (SINT32 argc, char*argv[]) 
{

///do something
}
```

I need to call a different function function 2 which is in bar.c and in a different directory and need to pass the same variable arguments as in Function 1.

**bar.c**

```
void Function2 (SINT32 argc, char *argv[])
{
// Do Something.

}
```

How Do I call Function2 from Function1 passing all the variable arguments received from console ?

Please Dont vote down as I am new to these concepts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using in *function1*, *function2(argc, argv);* what you get?

Comment: There are only 2 arguments: `argc` and `argv`.  You should pass the two of them.

Comment: This answer may be helpful for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/7882823/3421814

Comment: Using in function1 , function2(Argc,argv) i get undefined reference to function 2 . If I try to add the header file it complains : illegal usage of aggregate module ***.

Comment: Have you inserted in the foo.c file the `#include "bar.h"` in which there is the *declaration* of the function `Function2`?

Comment: Yes. I have included the declaration of the function

Answer (score 0):

Launching a program from the console always provides you 2 variables :

- *argc* : the number of console arguments, and
- *argv* : an array of strings in which all of your console arguments are stored

As said in comments, you just need to call these two args from function1 :

```
#include "bar.h"
void Function1 (SINT32 argc, char**argv[]) 
{
    Function2(argc, argv);
}
```

Don't forget to include both of your source codes when compiling :

```
gcc <opts> foo.c bar.c -o baz
```